# will there be changes to folders when WSL is installed?

Tags: nvidia, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cuda, jupyter, windows-11

I have a **NVIDIA Geforce RTX 3050** laptop with **Windows 11 OS**.
I had installed on Windows 11 **Anaconda3, Jupyter Notebook** using **conda** and it was working fine. I had installed CUDA 11.1 and associated CudNN files.

Since I wanted to install **Tensorflow** and it was written that WSL2 is essential for latest CUDA Versions, I installed WSL2 following the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install (installed **Ubuntu 22.0**)
and NVIDIA GPU support following the steps in https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html
**CUDA** version was changed to **12.1** as WSL2 supports 11.8 or higher
Then I installed **Miniconda** in Ubuntu following the steps in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

*Now I find that commands like conda list, jupyter-notebook etc are not working in Windows Command prompt.*

I find that there is **Windows** and **Windows.old** now in my file system (C:/ drive).

Kindly help me understand the issue(It might be a simple, but I am from electronics background) and how to run jupyter notebook in Windows while also using Ubuntu.

Comment: If you need help with Windows command prompt, you can ask on our sister site [Super User](https://superuser.com). We can't help with Windows problems. It's unclear how your issue is related to Ubuntu or WSL. [Windows.old has nothing to do with Ubuntu or WSL](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-is-windowsold-folder/487a63fd-b32c-47e2-9728-fdb9b91581b2) so it's likely that you're incorrect about this too.

Comment: the only software that I installed is wsl and cuda; thats why I raised it here.

Comment: If you have a question about Ubuntu, we can try to help you with that. But you haven't actually described or provided any details about any problems with Ubuntu. Focus on your *actual problem* and not whatever you think is the cause or solution, especially when you have little or no evidence or confidence that your assumptions are true. See: [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) If you want a prime example of the XY problem, you have a clear one in your question: Windows.old has absolutely nothing to do with Ubuntu in any capacity.